# minimal polynomial of an easy $3\times 3$ matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, minimal-polynomials

So I have a $3\times 3$ matrix, lets say...

$$ A= \begin{pmatrix}
1 &1  &0 \\ 
0 &1  &1 \\ 
0 &0  &1 
\end{pmatrix}.$$

If I calculate the characteristic polynomial, I get $(1-X)^3=0$. Now, the possible minimal polynomials are $(1-x)$ and $(1-x)^3$ (if I'm not wrong). Both can divide $(1-x)^3$ without any rest. Well, now the question: how can I choose between the two? If I'm not wrong, in this case, I can just take $(1-x)$ instead of $(1-x)^3$ because what I want is the polynomial with smaller degree. Is this correct?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the minimal polynomial could be $X - 1$ or $(X -1 )^{2}$ or $(X -1)^{3}$.

Just compute $(X -1 )^{2}$ on the given matrix $A$. To do that, note that $A - 1$ has a very simple form.

Comment: No sorry, what you mean for compute $(x-1)^2$ on A?

Comment: Substitute $A$ in $(X - 1)^{2}$. To check whether $(X - 1)^{2}$ or $X - 1$ is the minimal polynomial.

Comment: @OsvaldoPaniccia What's the minimal polynomial, then, if you do not know the meaning of "evaluating a polynomial in a matrix"?

Comment: To help with the calculation, if $e_{i}$ is the standard basis (column) vector, note that $A-1 : e_{3} \mapsto e_{2} \mapsto e_{1} \mapsto 0$. So $(A-1)^{2} : e_{3} \mapsto \dots$.

Comment: So if im not wrong i need to calculate: $\begin{pmatrix}
0 &0  &-1 \\ 
-1 &0  &0 \\ 
-1 &-1  &0 
\end{pmatrix}$ $\cdot$ $\begin{pmatrix}
0 &0  &-1 \\ 
-1 &0  &0 \\ 
-1 &-1  &0 
\end{pmatrix}$

Comment: Not quite, $A - 1 = \begin{pmatrix}
1 &1  &0 \\ 
0 &1  &1 \\ 
0 &0  &1 
\end{pmatrix} - \begin{pmatrix}
1 &0  &0 \\ 
0 &1  &0 \\ 
0 &0  &1 
\end{pmatrix} = \dots$. Here "$1$" denotes the identity matrix, not the matrix with $1$'s everywhere.

Comment: ooooohhhhh, i usually use  (A-1I) i get it, let me do...

Comment: @OsvaldoPaniccia, yes, you should definitely review the definitions!

Comment: Well in this case...

Comment: $\begin{pmatrix}
0 &1  &0 \\ 
0 &0  &1 \\ 
0 &0  &0 
\end{pmatrix}$ $\cdot$ $\begin{pmatrix}
0 &1  &0 \\ 
0 &0  &1 \\ 
0 &0  &0 
\end{pmatrix}$ = $\begin{pmatrix}
0 &0  &1 \\ 
0 &0  &0 \\ 
0 &0  &0 
\end{pmatrix}$  Wich is not equal to null matrix...

Comment: The solution is $(x-1)^3$! Because $(A-I)^3$=null matrix  Thanks to all! :)

Comment: Because $(A - I)^{3} - 0$ **and** $(A - I)^{2} \ne 0$, don't forget the second part.

Comment: Oh yes, in that case i should take $(A-I)^2$ because he has a smaller degree no?

Comment: I meant, $(A - I)^{3} = 0$, so the minimal polynomial is a divisor of $(X - 1)^{3}$. The monic, non-constant divisors of $(X - 1)^{3}$ are $X - 1$ and $(X-1)^{2}$, But since $(A - I)^{2} \ne 0$, $(X - 1)^{2}$ is not the minimal polynomial, and neither $X - 1$, as if $A - I = 0$, then $(A - I)^{2} = 0$.